# Download denied vimeo/pixabay video

Tags: video, vimeo, webrequest, pixabay

I have been using the pixabay api to search for and download selected videos. Lately some if not all of the video downloads are denied. I think it is vimeo doing the dening but I am not sure. One example is https://pixabay.com/videos/heart-shape-light-loop-17702/ From the api I get the download link of "https://player.vimeo.com/external/284467823.hd.mp4?s=4d290a926092dbb84458166ca26973edb229181f&profile_id=175&download=1". Do I need to include headers or authorizations with the request to get the download accepted? My app uses c# and WebReqest class to actually do the download. I can download the same video with a web browser so I do not believe it is actually a denied video but some incorrect parameter in my webrequest.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "From the api I get the download link of..." is that link coming from Pixabay's API, or from Vimeo's API? Download links from the Vimeo API expire every few hours; the response from the Vimeo API includes that expiry time. If Pixabay is caching the download link provided from the Vimeo API, Pixabay might need to refresh the Vimeo link. Just a guess at the moment without much more info.